# How to hide/show form elements after an option is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, forms

I'm making a form where an event information is in input. But here, If we select the option marriage, then 2 fields should appear. If we select session, then a single field should replace other two fields.

I have written the code below and I got no good result when executed.

```
<form class="talk-to-us" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <span class="<?php echo $errorType; ?>-msg"><?php echo $errorMsg; ?></span>
    <label class="fields">
        <div>Select event type:</div>
        <select id="ev-type" name="ev-type">
            <option value="session" selected>Session</option>
            <option value="marriage">Marriage</option>
            <option value="baby-shower">Baby Shower</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label name="session" id="session" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Event Name" name="event-name" required /></label>
    <label name="marriage" id="marriage" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Groom's Name" name="groom-name" required /></label>
    <label name="marriage" id="marriage" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Bride's Name" name="bride-name" required /></label>
    <label name="baby-shower" id="baby-shower" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Mother's Name" name="mother-name" required /></label>
    <label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="date" placeholder="Event Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" name="st-date" required /></label>
    <label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="date" placeholder="Event End Date (MM/DD/YYYY)" name="ed-date" /></label>
    <label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="time" placeholder="Event Start Time (24Hrs, IST Time)" name="st-time" required /></label>
    <label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="time" placeholder="Event End Time (24Hrs, IST Time)" name="ed-time" /></label>
    <label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="country" maxlength="20" placeholder="Event Country" name="event-country" required /></label>
    <label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><textarea type="text" maxlength="1200" placeholder="Event description. Describe your event with sole heart!" name="event-descrip" required></textarea></label>
    <label class="non-field"><input type="submit" value="Host my Event" name="event-submit" /></label>
</form>
<script>
    $("#ev-type").on("change", function() {
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
    })
</script>
```

I used this code and had a hope that the fields would Hide/Show on the basis of Selected Option. **All those fields are set to `display:none;`**.

Please help me further. I checked all other questions but I was helpless. So, this question is never a duplicate.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Have you included the jquery library ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya no, I haven't. What's jQuery library?

Comment: @KumarAbhirup You might want to format your code

Comment: @FlyingGambit what formating code? everything seems good.. ;/

Comment: @KumarAbhirup see this [`jquery`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixxry1-YLUAhUJTY8KHSB0AXoQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjquery.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFnz7C6MAXGLm7pVcOD_LrOjJUUiA)

Comment: @KumarAbhirup How can you tag a question with jquery if you don't know what it is?

Comment: @KumarAbhirup indentation is proper

Comment: Also the IDs should be unique, now you have two elements with the ID marriage

Answer (score 0):

Have updated sample code for you. Hope this helps.

```js
$("#ev-type").on("change", function() {
                switch($(this).val()) {
                  case 'marriage':
                    $(".fields").hide();
                    $("#ev-type-id, #groom-marriage, #bride-marriage").show();
                    break;
                   case 'session':
                   $(".fields").hide();
                    $("#ev-type-id, #session").show();
                   break;
                }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="talk-to-us" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<span class="<?php echo $errorType; ?>-msg"><?php echo $errorMsg; ?></span>
<label class="fields" id="ev-type-id">
  <div>Select event type:</div>
  <select id="ev-type" name="ev-type">
    <option value="session" selected>Session</option>
    <option value="marriage">Marriage</option>
    <option value="baby-shower">Baby Shower</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label name="session" id="session" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Event Name" name="event-name" required /></label>
<label name="marriage" id="groom-marriage" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Groom's Name" name="groom-name" required /></label>
<label name="marriage" id="bride-marriage" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Bride's Name" name="bride-name" required /></label>
<label name="baby-shower" id="baby-shower" class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Mother's Name" name="mother-name" required /></label>
<label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="date" placeholder="Event Start date (MM/DD/YYYY)" name="st-date" required /></label>
<label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="date" placeholder="Event End Date (MM/DD/YYYY)" name="ed-date" /></label>
<label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="time" placeholder="Event Start Time (24Hrs, IST Time)" name="st-time" required /></label>
<label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="time" placeholder="Event End Time (24Hrs, IST Time)" name="ed-time" /></label>
<label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><input type="country" maxlength="20" placeholder="Event Country" name="event-country" required /></label>
<label class="fields"><span><?php ?></span><textarea type="text" maxlength="1200" placeholder="Event description. Describe your event with sole heart!" name="event-descrip" required></textarea></label>
<label class="non-field"><input type="submit" value="Host my Event" name="event-submit" /></label>
       </form>
```

Comment: it works, but is incomplete. My whole form disappears. Only the requested field is alive.

Comment: Well, you can play around with JQuery to achieve what you want. You only need to show/hide based on whatever is selected from the dropdown.

Comment: But how can I achieve that? I'm unaware about jQuery. Only had bit knowledge about it

Answer (score 0):

lets do it in this manner,

```
$("#ev-type").on("change", function() {
     $id = $(this).val();
    $id('#' + $id).attr('display','block');
});
```

as you have mentioned that all other elements are set to display none, this will display the selected block

Comment: Thanks, but its in vain

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in the fields where you have given id as marriage. Kindly provide unique id values, as id = identifier. Giving same ids to multiple fields may result in conflict. Whereas same classname can be given to multiple fields.

```
         $('#ev-type').on('change', function() {
            var selectedType = this.value ;
             if(selectedType == 'marriage'){
                $('.marriage').hide(); 
                // write code to show the session fields
              }
              else if(selectedType == 'session'){
                $('.marriage').show();
                // write code to hide session fields
              }
          });
```